# Modal is not working when use Data Table with server side pagination even no script is working when click on button or <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to open a modal on `<a>` tag click using jquery but when i click on `<a>` tag jquery not hitting. May be because i am getting table dynamically from controller in `JSON` formate and it is not bind to the JS. although i am getting results in my view perfect problem is only with the `modal`.

**Controller**

```
public function dataProcessing(Request $request)
    {

        $columns = array(
            0 => 'case_number',
            1 => 'patient',
            2 => 'name',
            3 => 'created_at',
            4 => 'action'
        );

        $totalData = PrimaryCaseNo::count();
        $limit = $request->input('length');
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

        if (empty($request->input('search.value'))) {
            $posts = PrimaryCaseNo::offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
            $totalFiltered = PrimaryCaseNo::count();
        } else {
            $search = $request->input('search.value');
            $posts = PrimaryCaseNo::where('patient', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('case_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
            $totalFiltered = PrimaryCaseNo::where('patient', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('case_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->count();
        }

        $data = array();

        if ($posts) {
            foreach ($posts as $r) {
                $nestedData['case_number'] = $r->case_number;
                $nestedData['patient'] = $r->patient;
                $nestedData['created_at'] = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($r->created_at))->isoFormat('MMM Do YY');
                $nestedData['action'] = '
                    <a href="#!" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</a>

                    <a id="' . $r->id . '" class="btn btn-default impression-case-list" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl"data-keyboard="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>



                ';
                $data[] = $nestedData;
            }

        }

        $json_data = array(
            "draw" => intval($request->input('draw')),
            "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
            "data" => $data
        );

        echo json_encode($json_data);

    }
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            <i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>
            Case Stages
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
            <li class="active">General Elements</li>
        </ol>
    </section>

    <section class="content">

        @include('company.case_stages')

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Impression Case List</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th>Case Number</th>
                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                        {{--                        <th>Operator</th>--}}
                        <th>Case Registered</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                <div class="modal-content">


                    <div id="casesList"></div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->

    </section>

@endsection
@section('script')

@section('script')

    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>

        $('#example1').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?= route('dataProcessing') ?>",
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {"_token": "<?= csrf_token() ?>"}
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "case_number"},
                {"data": "patient"},
                // {"data": "patient"},
                {"data": "created_at"},
                {"data": "action", "searchable": false, "orderable": false}
            ]


        });
    </script>

<script>
         $('a').on('click', '.impression-case-list', function () {

                alert('hi');

                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('show-impression-case-list-ajax-call')}}",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        id: id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // console.log(data.html);
                        // $('#caseNumberList').fadeIn();
                        $('#casesList').html(data.html);

                    }
                });
            });
</script>

@endsection

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer finally after tring many things the following works

```
$(document).on('click', '.impression-case-list', function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('show-impression-case-list-ajax-call')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(data.html);
                // $('#caseNumberList').fadeIn();
                $('#casesList').html(data.html);

            }
        });
    });
```